# Changing CSS Div Position Value Given in % Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to click a button and change a div value given in % to move the div off screen at the click of a button.

However, the code below produces no result when the button is clicked. I really appreciate any advice I can get.

```js
function Shift() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Lac");
  if (x.style.left === "0%" && x.style.top === "0%") {
    x.style.left = "100%";
    x.style.top = "100%";
  }
}
```

```css
#Lac {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  background-color: #0062FF;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="Lac">
  <button onclick="Shift()">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: worth noting that you may not be able to simply repost in case if you're [question blocked there](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7020/31260) (are you?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:** I suggest you remove the if-statement. It doesn't do any good.

```js
function Shift() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Lac");
  x.style.left = "100%";
  x.style.top = "100%";
}
```

```css
#Lac {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  background-color: #0062FF;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="Lac">
  <button onclick="Shift()">Button</button>
</div>
```

**Solution 2:** Add a className instead of all that JavaScript.

```css
#Lac {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  background-color: #0062FF;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
#Lac.hide {
  left: 100%;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="Lac">
  <button onclick="this.parentNode.className='hide';">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate the help. Solution 2 worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve the value from `.style.left` you need to do the following:

```
 var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("Lac"))
 console.log(style.left); //outputs 0px
 var left = parseInt(style.left); //0
if ( !left ){
    //do the animation
}
```